# Washing Machine Hookups Not Shutting Off

Tags: water, washing-machine

My neighbor is trying to hook up a new washing machine.  We have turned the valves on the wall both ways, specifically to the direction that says off though and when we unhook the pipe from the washing machine, water still shoots out.  Is there something we are missing?  I put a bucket underneath and slightly turned the connector going into the washer and water started shooting out, so I turned the knob both ways and there didn't seem to be a change in the pressure.

Comment: Are these quarter-turn valves or old-style, multi-turn globe valves?  (From the failure mode, it sounds like the latter, but I want to make sure.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the faucets that are in the lines to the washing machine hookup have been in the ON state for years the internal seals are likely deteriorated so that they no longer will function. If you have a water supply with a lot of minerals the water they may have deposited on the inside of the faucets to the point that it is not possible to turn them off.

To get past the immediate connection problem you can turn off the main supply valve where water pipes come into the property. However it would be strongly recommended to replace these faulty faucets as soon as possible. Last thing you need is to be standing there by your washer when a hose bursts and you cannot quickly shut off the faucets behind the washer.

Comment: Yeah that was the issue. Both valves were bad.  We shut off the main supply and had to replace them.